# How to get the revision content from google drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api

In google document, when you check the revisions, it will shows for each revision, who was editing and what they had edit. Right now I am using https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk to get the google drive information. Right now I can get most of the detail for google drive like all the files' id, name, how many revisions for each file. But there is a problem, for the revision.get() method I only able to get each revision's id, lastmodifiedUser,when they modify each revision. I can't get what changes they have made in each revision, neither the amount of words have been edit. In the developer website it provide some object that will shows the size of changes in revision. But it mentions that it only work for binary file in google drive. It also told us that you won't able to the google doc,sheet detail revision information. Does anyone know how to get the words changes from google drive revisions?
This is the code to get the revision information.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from googleapiclient.discovery import build

from httplib2 import Http

from oauth2client import file, client, tools

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'

def main():

    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=2, fields="nextPageToken, files(size,id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])
    print(items)
    response = service.changes().list(pageToken=1,
                                            spaces='drive').execute()
    for change in response.get('changes'):
        # Process change
        print( 'Change found for file: %s' % change.get('fileId'))
    if 'newStartPageToken' in response:
        # Last page, save this token for the next polling interval
        saved_start_page_token = response.get('newStartPageToken')
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')

    results = service.revisions().list(
        fileId='1KlrFKGxmqKMxjdEx-NoJ1ApG5qvlaKBMA7ZdVcITzGY',
                ).execute()
    items = results
    print(items,"\n")




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this. See this answer: [How can I get the revision history in Google Docs using a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180902/how-can-i-get-the-revision-history-in-google-docs-using-a-script)

The only information available via the API is the information listed on this endpoint, which you mentioned: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions

Comment: Yeah I had seen some similar question post before. Then forget about the changes of revision. Is it possible to get those users who edit in a revision?Like in a revision three people edit the document. Can we get these three users' information or we only able to get the lastmodifyuser?