# Get last modified page

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

How do I get **page number**, **which is modified** (deleting/adding content) in Google doc, Google Slide in last modification time?

I have used Google drive revision (advanced API) ,but I can only get last modified date and the whole content of a document.

```
 var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(*fileId*);
```

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible :( , read the docs here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive.   Also another stack question regarding this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180902/how-can-i-get-the-revision-history-in-google-docs-using-a-script

Comment: Compute the changes - as you say, you have the whole document content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Drive Advance Service is the same as the Google Drive REST API, as according to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive):

> For detailed information on this service, [see the reference
>   documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/) for the Google Drive web API.

And as far as I can see, after a brief review, there are no methods readably available for seeing which Google Docs page that has been edit.