# How Can I Get a Full List of Versions with Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to get a full list of revisions/versions from a Google Doc's version history. Using the code provided by @Ben Gidley in his answer to [How can I get the revision history in Google Docs using a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180902/how-can-i-get-the-revision-history-in-google-docs-using-a-script) I can get the "[grouped versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoZYK.png)"
but I want [all the versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQHSs.png).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible and is an expected behavior of the API stated here: [Changes and revisions overview](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/change-overview#:%7E:text=Up%20to%20200%20revisions%20can,%22Keep%20Forever%22%20is%20purgeable.)

---

***Revision History***

A record of all revisions of a file in chronological order. A change to a Docs, Sheets, or Slides file gets a new revision. Each time the content changes, Drive creates a new revision history entry for that file. However, these editor file revisions may be merged together, so the API response might not show all changes to a file.

Comment: That's disappointing. Thanks for the info.